# Early Shabbos Amira lakum

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, amira-leakum

If a Jew made early Shabbos, I see the mechaber in [OC 263:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.263.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that one may ask a Jew to do melacha for him (assuming he did not accept Shabbos yet).

Would the same hold true of asking a non-Jew to do melacha when one made early Shabbos?

Answer (score 3):

[R Doniel Schreiber](https://etzion.org.il/en/authors/rav-doniel-schreiber) answers your question [here](https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/shabbat/accepting-early-shabbat) (point #6)

> **In the period of early Shabbat when most Jews have not yet accepted
> Shabbat, one who has accepted Shabbat is permitted to ask non-Jews to
> perform melakha for him even if it is not for the purpose of a mitzva.**
> However, once most Jews have accepted Shabbat, it is permitted only if
> it is for the needs of Shabbat, up until tzeit ha-kokhavim ([OC
> 261:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.261.1?lang=bi) and [MB 261:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.261.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))